# emacs scratch not interactive mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, interactive

I updated a lot of packages that I had directly from github to the MELPA packages. Nonetheless something really weird happened to my ***scratch*** buffer. The default message is not appearing (the buffer is completely empty), and also the interactive elisp mode is not set (let's say I write `(+ 2 2)` and then hit `C-j` and it tells me invalid function). I have no idea why. I don't even know how to debug it to check where the error is. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there anything interesting in `*Messages*`?

Comment: Nothing that interesting, the only weird messages I have are `Error while loading 50dictionaries-common` and `[yas] Discovered there was already *scratch* in fundamental-mode` but I don't thing it has something to do with it.

Comment: What's `50dictionaries-common`?

Comment: Can't you just switch to `fundamental-mode` again?

Comment: @Chris: I don't exactly know about the 50dictionaries thing, but it should be related to ispell. @Andrew `fundamental-mode` is active but not working, I need to do `M-x lisp-interaction-mode` and then it works, but it's kind of cumbersome

Comment: As always, recursively bisect your init file, to find out what is causing the change in behavior (assuming you don't see the behavior with `emacs -Q`). You can use `comment-region` to comment out a region of text (and with `C-u` it uncomments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was generated by `flycheck-add-next-checker`, for some reason, using the MELPA repositories is generating this error. I just commented the following part of my configuration file.

```
 (eval-after-load 'flycheck
   '(progn
       ;; Add Google C++ Style checker.
       ;; In default, syntax checked by Clang and Cppcheck.
       (flycheck-add-next-checker 'c/c++-clang
           '(warnings-only . c/c++-googlelint))))
```